# Exchange 2010 outlook anywhere - shows internal URL

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I am setting up an Exchange 2010 SP2 for a customer.

However, the server address that the server returns with autodiscover is wrong, as it points to the internal domain (.local) - and not the external address.

How do I change this?

Here's an image to describe what I mean:

[image: Image to describe it]
It is the upper field that is wrong.

I dont want users to enable the RPC over HTTP-thing, as the users know barely nothing about computers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the server address that the server returns with autodiscover is wrong."  In what client program are you seeing this address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

First, I created a CAS array, with the one server as member (sounds ridiculous to me, but it worked).

Then I changed the mailbox's rpc cas server address with help from [this link](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-2010-cas-array)

Finally, I noticed that I needed to open port 28755 and port 6008 in the firewall for it all to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change all of this using the Exchange Shell but I did a quick search and came across this [PowerShell Script](http://msunified.net/exchange-downloads/script-internalexternalurls-ps1/) which may take some of the pain out of it.  I have not tested or used it but it looks like it calls all of the right things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try to look at that script.

Comment: Allright, looked a bit into it, ran it, and setup both internal and external URL's to be the same (the external FQDN). However - this hasn't helped at all. Outlook still tries to connect to the local address, which cant be done as it doesnt exist on the remote machine.

Comment: Your internal address SHOULD be your internal FQDN for your domain: mail.mydomain.local.  Unless your domain is a public domain, which from your screenshot it is not, this should never be a public FQDN.  Only the external name should be.  I'm a little confused when you say "cant be done as it doesnt exist on the remote machine" what does that mean?

Comment: What I mean is, that the machine connecting to the exchange server has no idea where to find exchange.server.local - as they are not in the same physical location, and are not going to be.

Comment: @FrederikNielsen Hmm, once you update the external URLs the autodiscover service should start returning that URL, try restarting the Autodiscover service to see if it updates.  You can also use https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ to verify the autodiscover settings.

Comment: Exactly what service do you mean with the autodiscover service? I cannot seem to find any related to that in the services view. I tried restarting the IIS, with no success.
testexchangeconnectivity doesn't work for me, as I am not using commercial certificates.

Comment: Sorry, havving run IISReset /noforce should have done it.  The autodiscover response should be providing the internal server name to use as well as the external OWA server name.  Really not sure why it wouldn't be.

Comment: I just ran iisreset, as with the noforce switch, it doesnt restart the service (not sure why..) I tried running Outlook's own auto configure test, and everything seems fine, except for the part under protocol: Exchange RCP - in there it states the .local FQDN, and not the public FQDN.

Comment: Alright, got the first part fixed. Solved it by [setting up a CAS array](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-2010-cas-array)
Now, outlook states that it cannot find the user, as it has no connectivity to the exchange server. Any ideas?